# have some questions about github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

unrelated, but let me ask, after I uploaded the code to the github page, when running the web, the css and javascript were lost, can someone help me??

1 / I tried checking but the path is still correct ?
2/ My code uploaded successfully 8 hours ago

Comment: What CSS and JavaScript?  That of your code?   Are you sure those were pushed to GitHub?

Comment: I'm very sure, Each file has been successfully uploaded, but for some reason, when entering the page, the css is missing

Comment: So what page are you referring to? One in Github, or a deployed site that comes from the Github respository?

Comment: Specifically, this is it. I uploaded the code to have my own domain name to share with friends. All files are fully uploaded, but when I go to the website domain name (which is the domain name of that github page), it only shows html.

Comment: You are going to have to do some debugging and provide more information, because as it currently stands, we can't diagnose what is wrong and give you an answer, and your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.